# Serial.print() not fully printing

Tags: arduino-uno

println() function is being used to send AT commands to GSM module.

```
sim800l.println("AT+CLTS=1");
  delay(3000);
  sim800l.println("AT+COPS=2");
  delay(3000);
  sim800l.println("AT+COPS=0,0");
  delay(3000);
```

But problem is the output -

```
AT+CLTS=1

OK
AT+COP
```

The command AT+COP did not print fully? Why?
Minimal Reproducable Example -

```
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>    //Library required for serial communication
char MYDATA[18];
SoftwareSerial sim800l(3, 2); // RX,TX for Arduino and for the module it's TXD RXD, they should be inverted
void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600); //Start the serial interface on 9600
  sim800l.begin(9600);
  delay(100);
  // AT command to set sim800l to SMS mode
  sim800l.println("AT+CMGF=1"); 
  //Serialcom();
  delay(100);
  // Set module to send SMS data to serial out upon receipt 
  sim800l.println("AT+CNMI=2,2,0,0,0");
  delay(100);
  sim800l.println("AT+CLTS=1");
  delay(3000);
  sim800l.println("AT+COPS=2");
  delay(3000);
  sim800l.println("AT+COPS=0,0");
  delay(3000);
   sim800l.println("AT+CCLK?");
  Serial.find("+CCLK: \"");
  Serial.readBytesUntil('\+', MYDATA, 17);

}

void loop() {
 Serial.print(MYDATA);
}
```

Comment: How / Where do you see the output and the response?

Comment: @DataFiddler Arduino Serial Monitor

Comment: Could you provide a minimal, complete, reproducible example?
https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: ... please expand your code snippet to show this Serial Monitor output, too (at least). A minimal but complete test sketch were even better, of course.

Comment: Nothing in that code should print to the serial monitor. Show *all* your code.

Comment: @Majenko Ok Ok please wait a minute. till then sim800l is Software Serial library.

Comment: @Majenko Please See.

Comment: @FilipFranik Please see.

Comment: @DataFiddler Please see.

Comment: Thanks for the changed code: You send some commands to your sim800l. Then you try to read from Serial. If there should arrive anything, you return a few of those characters repeatedly forever.Your `Serial.find` will probably time out. Your `Serial.readBytesUntil` will probably timeout too, and will get you at most 17 characters.

Comment: BTW: `warning: unknown escape sequence: '\+'` in your `readBytesUntil`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're overflowing the serial receive buffer. There's only a limited amount of space (64 bytes normally, maybe less in SoftwareSerial) for receiving data before you must read it or lose data. Since you are just blindly throwing commands at the SIM800 and not doing anything with its responses until right at the end all that incoming data fills the receive buffer to overflowing.

Your methodology is flawed (not your fault, the examples on the internet are all rubbish and teach you the wrong way of doing things). What you should be doing is issuing a command then receiving the response back and parsing it to see if the command was successful or not, and retrieve any information that the response may include that you would want to know.

Comment: I do not want any  info from the commands. I just want to blindly issue the command. How can I empty the buffer?

Comment: Read it.  Or if you don't care what it returns why are you even bothering to display anything at all?

Comment: Because the last command, I want to read the AT+CCLK result. My module does not gets latest time. So the all commands are neccessary so that AT+CCLK returns correct date.

Comment: So you *do* want to read and interpret the responses then. At the very least you should be reading after *every* command and looking for either OK or ERR and discarding everything else.

Comment: I am very confused. If I open my own minimal reproducable example, there is no serial output. Then how come I was getting the output in my original code?

Comment: No idea. Write yourself a simple line-by-line reader / comparison routine that you can run after each command (except the one you're interested in) that returns a TRUE/FALSE result depending on if it finds OK or ERR. Do things properly from the start and things will be simpler later one.

Comment: Isn't there some command to empty Serial Buffer?

Comment: Yes. read. `while (sim800l.available()) { sim800l.read(); }`